# how to access ul elements created by jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

i have some jquery logic, below is the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('<ul class="className"><\/ul>').insertBefore('.divClassName');
    $.each(jsArray, function(key, value) {
        $('<li><input class="dynamicFilterInput" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="' + key + '" id="filterID' + key + '" /><label for="filterID' + key + '"> ' + value + ' <\/label><\/li>').appendTo('ul.afilters');
    });
});
```

above code is making dynamic `<ul><li></li>...</ul>` and then i have ajax call and on complete i need to update that `ul` list,

i have function defined for `ul` like below

```
$('.ULclassName input').click(function() {
    alert("aaaaaaaaaaa");
});
```

this function is accessible when page load, but after my ajax call when i update ul list and click on checkbox, nothing happens, i see no alert,

how to access to `$('.ULclassName input').click( function() {});` ?

**Edit:** this is `complete` call back logic in my ajax call

```
complete: function(){
$('ul.className').hide();

$('<ul class="className"><\/ul>').insertBefore('.divClassName');
    $.each(jsArray, function(key, value) {
        $('<li><input class="dynamicFilterInput" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="' + key + '" id="filterID' + key + '" /><label for="filterID' + key + '"> ' + value + ' <\/label><\/li>').appendTo('ul.afilters');
    });

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind using live
Try:

```
$('.ULclassName input').live("click", function() {
    alert("aaaaaaaaaaa");
});
```

With `.on`:

```
$(document).on("click", '.ULclassName input', function() {
    alert("aaaaaaaaaaa");
});
```

Comment: Dont use live it is depreciated

Comment: @ubercooluk you still shouldn't downvote this, it's a `document` delegation alias for `.on`  anyway

Comment: thanks mate ! i was missing .live, is it deprecated right ? `.on` is working correctly,

Comment: @user1458253 both the snippets are exactly equivalent. But you should use the `.on` one.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use the jQuery `.on()` functionality.

More specific info can be found in the jQuery manual here:
http://api.jquery.com/on/

It can be called in several ways depending on if your using a bind, delegate, or live.

```
// Bind
$('.ULclassName input').on( "click", function(){
    alert("aaaaaaaaaaa");
});

//Delegate
$(".ULclassName").on("click", "input", function(){
    alert("aaaaaaaaaaa");
});

//Live
$( document ).on( "click", ".ULclassName input", function() {
    alert("aaaaaaaaaaa");
} );
```

In jQuery < 1.7 , these were previously used like so:

```
// Bind
$( ".ULclassName input" ).bind( "click", function( e ) {} ); 

// Live 
$( ".ULclassName input" ).live( "click", function( e ) {} );

// Delegate
$( ".ULclassName" ).delegate( "input", "click", function( e ) {} );
```

I think you probably want to use the one for LIVE.

Comment: this is great, thanks for interest, i wonder y u had down-vote, thanks for interest

Comment: I was down voted as i my original answer was the `.on()` functionality for bind, which would have been wrong.

Answer (score 0):

How about using delegate ?

```
$('body').delegate('.ULclassName input', 'click', function(){
    alert("aaaaaaaaaaa");
});
```